# how can I set CharacterCasing property on avalonedit?

Tags: avalonedit

I need only Uppercase on avalonedit.

how can I attach the property? Or is there any other alternate way?

Comment: now i add TextEntered Handler on TextArea. and check input text, select one character and replace it(Uppercase). plz let me know if u know better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in feature for that.

I think the best way to implement this is to handle the `TextArea.TextEntering` event. If the input text isn't all uppercase, abort the text input by setting `e.Handled = true;`, and call `TextArea.PerformTextInput()` again with the uppercase version.